# MCreator: net.minecraft.world.World missing, but should be detected

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

**Scenario**
I made an MCreator 2023.2 project using the Fabric plugin targeting Minecraft 1.19.2, and I want my block to react to redstone by changing blockstate. For this I need to import `net.minecraft.world.World` and call `World.setBlockState()`. I'm overriding `neighborChanged()` in my class that extends Block. This is all strictly expected, vetted by my friend's code, online tutorials and references to these functions in multiple places.

**Problem**
Intellisense reports `net.minecraft.world.World` does not exist (it has no entry for `World`). Build fails on this, saying the symbol can't be found, but this should exist. Adding a procedure on neighbor changed and viewing its code reveals a weird discrepancy. The override for neighborChanged should be:

```
public void neighborChanged(BlockState state, World worldIn, BlockPos pos, Block blockIn, BlockPos fromPos)
```

but is:

```
public void neighborChanged(BlockState state, Level world, BlockPos pos, Block blockIn, BlockPos neighborBlock, boolean moving)
```

as registered by the procedure. The instance world unsurprisingly doesn't have `setBlockState()`.

I need `net.minecraft.world.World` to be recognized. I did no manual tweaking outside this one block file. My mod is very small currently. My friend also made a brand new repo with the fabric plugin and encountered this issue, so it's been repro'd. I'm hoping it's not broken for all users. I can provide a MRE as needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot create question tags. MCreator is software that's been referenced a few times in other questions and could use its own tag, if anyone thinks it's worthy enough, so I could edit it out of the title.